# rails update action not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, postman

I have following table in database and also the model created for it.

```
|id  |name   |description |created_date           |updated_date       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1   |HELLO  |greeting    |2017-09-28 18:51:51    |2017-09-28 18:51:51|
```

**model.rb**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :person_activities
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

I want to create `update` action in **controller**. It will update the name and description based on the name passed. e.g i want to update the name *HELLO* to **HI**. How can i create update action for that?

I tried following `update` action in **controller** but it wont hit the `update` action

```
  def update
    byebug
    redirect_to Person.find(name: params[:id]).tap { |person|
      person.update!(person_params)
    }
  end

  private

  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name)
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :person, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy], defaults: { format: :json }
```

Tried testing like this `http://localhost:1111/person/HELLO` and passing `{ name: 'HI'}` in body params. I am using **postman** for testing.

Comment: you need to add an entry in `config/routes.rb` - normally update is done through the `PUT` HTTP request type so it won't be accessible by typing a URL in your address bar (which only sends a GET request). You'll either need to use a HTTP client like Postman to test it, or write an HTML form. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: I have the entry added in routes.rb. I am using postman please see the line at the end

Comment: Did you set the HTTP method in postman to PUT?

Comment: yes i did set the action to PUT

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your model, something like this:

```
class Person< ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :change_name

  private

    def change_name
      self.name="HI" if self.name=="HELLO"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this properly we would need to understand the logic of how creating a new record with name = "HELLO" would need to be set to "HI".  Do you have a lookup table for this logic or is it hardcoded?

The easiest thing I could think of is you can change the value of the passed parameter before doing the update by setting the value of the parameter.  E.G.

```
params["name"] = "HI"
```

So when you do a person.update it will use the "name" param set to "HI".

Then you could do this in a

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    params["name"] = "HI"
    if @person.update(person_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

You could also do the update then just set the value after the update:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.update(person_params)
       @person.name = "HI"
       @person.save
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

From postman you need to call login action first. So it will create a session in postman and then you can call update action.